# A hierarchical conditional probability problem

Tags: probability

This confusion is haunting me around for a long time.
Suppose we know $$f_{3|2},f_{2|1},f_{1}$$ are iid  distributed. And here comes the problem. If we want to find the joint distribution of $f_{1,2,3}$, can we directly say $f_{1,2,3}=f_{3|2}f_{2|1}f_{1}$? Because what I'm thinking is that, from the definition of conditional probability, the equation should be like$$f_{1,2,3}=f_{3|2,1}f_{2|1}f_{1}$$
So here, does it means that $$f_{3|2,1}=f_{3|2}$$ Is it right?

Comment: 1. Saying $f_{3 \mid 2}, f_{2 \mid 1}, f_1$ are "i.i.d." is kind of weird. What exactly do you mean by that? 2. I think you are looking for something like "variables 1 and 3 are conditionally independent given 2," in which case $f_{3 \mid 2,1}=f_{3 \mid 2}$ does hold and you get what you want. Without some condition like this, you are right, we can only say $f_{1,2,3} = f_{3 \mid 2,1} f_{2 \mid 1} f_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 1. what I mean here is $X_3|X_2$ $X_2|X_1$ $X_1$ are iid. 2. I'm think whether we can say $f_{3,2,1}=f_{3|2}f_{2|1}f_{1}$, because in some place, they just say this is true without giving the condition that $X_{1|2}$ and $X_{3|2}$ are independent. I wonder if they implicitly mean it but just never it write down.

Comment: 1. This is still a bit weird... 2. Right, that is not true in general, so there must be some implicit assumption.